# Saving an image from image control to gallery in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, image-gallery

I have a image in a Image control like below:

```
<Image x:name="myImg" Source="Images/MyImg.png" />
```

How can I save this image in to the image gallery so that I can see by going to the gallery folder.

I have tried different codes but I am not able to save it. Please help me on this.

**EDIT:**

I have image in control in List Box. I am binding the list box with the IList that is coming from the web service.

So after Binding the image if user want to save the image he can save the particular which he want to save.

So how can i save the that particular image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent MSDN article that describes this very scenario:
[How to: Encode a JPEG for Windows Phone and Save to the Pictures Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769549%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Incidentally , it's also the first search result link when searching for `windows phone save image to media library` on both [Google](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&q=windows%20phone%20save%20image%20to%20media%20library&oq=windows%20phone%20save%20image%20to&aq=1K&aqi=g-K2g-b1g-bK1&aql=&gs_l=hp.11.1.0i30l2j0i8j0i8i30.212.12947.0.14140.48.32.0.13.13.2.246.4033.7j20j3.30.0...0.0.MMYoB4IDSbg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=59f849ff23f382f&biw=1010&bih=783&pf=p&pdl=300) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+phone+save+image+to+library&qs=AS&form=QBLH&pq=windows+phone+save+ima&sc=3-22&sp=2&sk=AS1).

Have you tried following this guide, and if so what are you having problems with?

The essential code to save it:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a file name for the JPEG file in isolated storage.
    String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

    // Create a virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
    var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }

    IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);


    // Create a stream out of the sample JPEG file.
    // For [Application Name] in the URI, use the project name that you entered 
    // in the previous steps. Also, TestImage.jpg is an example;
    // you must enter your JPEG file name if it is different.
    StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
    Uri uri = new Uri("[Application Name];component/TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

    // Create a new WriteableBitmap object and set it to the JPEG stream.
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
    bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

    // Encode the WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
    wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    myFileStream.Close();

    // Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
    myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // Save the image to the camera roll or saved pictures album.
    MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

    if (radioButtonCameraRoll.IsChecked == true)
    {
        // Save the image to the camera roll album.
        Picture pic = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("SavedPicture.jpg", myFileStream);
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to camera roll album");
    }
    else
    {
        // Save the image to the saved pictures album.
        Picture pic = library.SavePicture("SavedPicture.jpg", myFileStream);
        MessageBox.Show("Image saved to saved pictures album");
    }

    myFileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply Magnus. My Image control is binding dynamically and it is in ListBox control. So i cant get the URL to use your line of code (i.e: Uri uri = new Uri("[Application Name];component/TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);) so i want to save the image after binding the image. How can i do this?

Comment: You have not mentioned this at all in your question. Please update your question with that information.